# PHP: obdc_exec() fails silently in a Zend Model

Tags: php, zend-framework, odbc, netezza

I am trying to connect to a Netezza database via ODBC (not really important).

What's important is that I'm trying to wrap manual odbc calls in a Zend Model. There is no ODBC adapter for Zend. I found one that ends up having the same issue I am coming across now, so I'm hoping that it's the same problem and I can ditch the manual hackery if I get it solved. I also tried a PDO object, but it had the same issues.

So the code is like this (with parameters obviously faked for public viewing):

```
$conn = odbc_connect('dsn','username','password');
$sql = "SELECT site_name FROM sites";
$test = odbc_exec($conn, $sql) or die(odbc_errormsg());
echo "Made it this far.";
```

Here's the issue: When I paste those four lines into a standalone file, it works and that last line will echo. I can then actually pull the data from $test and spit it out. However, if I paste those four lines into a method within a custom model, odbc_exec() silently fails. That last line doesn't echo. The connection is being made and $conn is totally a resource, but it just stops during odbc_exec(). If it's a huge query, it takes really long and then stops/fails/does nothing.

I have no idea why this is happening and I am going insane. Zend shouldn't be messing with this at all, those lines are completely standalone.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: did anything appear in php error log?

Comment: Found this in error_log: [Thu Jan 26 12:43:13 2012] [notice] child pid 28979 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /var/tmp/core  This shows up each time I try to run the script.

Comment: just guessing - maybe try to check the dump? Like in http://serverfault.com/questions/297688/advice-for-debugging-apache-with-php-segmentation-faults/299592#299592 OR try to make memry_limit higher?

Comment: The memory_limit is 512M already... PHP has complained to me verbally before about the memory limit being too small, I would imagine that it'd do it again. I'll check the dump.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem. Update unix_odbc and PHP to the latest and it works like a charm.